# Jsoup timeouts without fetching data

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, http-headers, web-crawler, jsoup

I have the following line of code to fetch a html document using jsoup

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/hrrr/prod/hrrr.20180904/conus/")
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0")
            .header("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
            .header("Host", "nomads.ncep.noaa.gov")
            .timeout(10*1000)
            .get();
```

This times out no  matter what headers I use. The same url :

```
http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/hrrr/prod/hrrr.20180904/conus/
```

works completely fine when I punch it  in Chrome or Firefox. What am I missing here? Thanks a lot in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, [this site](http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/hrrr/prod/hrrr.20180904/conus/) is very slow, It takes 30 seconds to load in average (you can see by loading in the browser). So you need to put timeout around 50 seconds.

This should resolve your problem...

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/hrrr/prod/hrrr.20180904/conus/")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0")
                .header("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
                .header("Host", "nomads.ncep.noaa.gov")
                .timeout(50000)
                .get();
```

Comment: Thanks @gaurav. Fortunately I figured out the same when I was trying different values to make it work!